# In Elixir, how can I traverse a list within another loop?

Tags: elixir

Given two lists and a third list which has values that map to the permutations of the first two, I would like to create a Map of list1's key, list2's key, and list3's value.  How can I get list3's value at a certain index if I am inside the loop?

Using `Enum.at` is not the correct solution for this, I understand - it will traverse the whole list on every iteration.  And if I try `[head | tail] = list3`, it looks like I can't just set `list3 = tail` for the next loop.

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [3,4]
list3 = 'wxyz'

Enum.each(list1), fn i ->
  Enum.each(list2), fn j ->
    # Would like to just chop off the first value of list3 and 
    # pass the tail into the next iteration
  end
end
```

Comment: Since my solution is unworkable regardless of Enum.at, I've removed it. But the idiomatic way to code a nested loop in Elixir is with Comprehensions.

Comment: BTW you will find it really hard to do anything better than O(n)  performance in this case because an Elixir list is a linked list under the  hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a longtime rubyist, throwing down `.each` became about as natural as breathing for me.  After writing Elixir for a while now, `.each` has almost become a code smell for me-  whenever I use it by reflex, I end up going back to remove it, because it leads to awkward Elixir code.

As mentioned in comments, a comprehension is idiomatic for "looping":  if you don't mind traversing 3 times, the following works:

```
result = for i <- list1, j <- list2, do: {i, j}
         |> Enum.zip(list3) 
         |> Enum.into(%{})

iex> result
%{{1, 3} => 119, {1, 4} => 120, {2, 3} => 121, {2, 4} => 122}
```

You may choose to write it as a full-fledged function instead, especially if your example was a simplification of something more complicated.  The following functions only traverse `list3` once:

```
defmodule MapLists do
  def map_it(l1, l2, l3, acc \\ %{})
  def map_it([], _l2, _l3, acc), do: acc
  def map_it([h|t], list2, list3, acc) do
    {res1, new_list_3} = do_map_it(h, list2, list3, %{})
    new_acc = Map.merge(acc, res1)
    map_it(t, list2, new_list_3, new_acc)
  end


  defp do_map_it(item, [], l3, acc), do: {acc, l3}
  defp do_map_it(item, [h2|t2], [h3|t3], acc) do
    new_acc = Map.put(acc, {item, h2}, h3)
    do_map_it(item, t2, t3, new_acc)
  end
end
```

and usage:

```
iex> MapLists.map_it([1,2],[3,4],'wxyz')
%{{1, 3} => 119, {1, 4} => 120, {2, 3} => 121, {2, 4} => 122}
```

Comment: The second answer was exactly what I was looking for - I'm looking for leanness above all else.  I'm also jumping into Elixir from a Ruby world.

Comment: @DonPflaster I was fortunate to have a very experienced erlang programmer help me make the transition... based on my experience, I  *strongly* recommend writing raw erlang for a while, which will teach you loads about elixir

Comment: I had a feeling instinctively that I wasn't going to find something elegant-looking for what I wanted to do.  We're certainly not using this language for elegance. :)  Thanks for the great answer.